# Formatting of html is lost when indexing data using Nutch hbase

Tags: java, solr, hbase, nutch

I am trying to crawl Sample html files in Nutch hbase setup and when I retrieve the `NutchDocument` (`org.apache.nutch.indexer.NutchDocument`) to read content, I am getting data in text format as below

```
    tstamp: [1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z]
    digest: [52e6d9e5e5e96e2cfac7fcd92cd117f8]
    host:   []
    boost:  [1.0]
    id:     [:file/home/file.html]
    title:  [Nutch1]
    url:    [file:///home/file.html]
    content:        [Nutch1 Nutch1 The Apache Nutch PMC are pleased to announce the immediate release of Apache Nutch v1.11, we advise all current users and developers of the 1.X series to upgrade to this release. Nutch-Nutch-Identifies the overall Positive]
```

But what I am expecting is the raw content of html and not the text.

Is there any setting which I am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into the [index-html](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/src/plugin/index-html) plugin on the 2.x branch.

This plugin will allow you to index the raw HTML content of the documents. By default Nutch parse/extracts and index the textual content only, all the HTML tags are ignored by default.

Comment: Will it be also applicable to word ,pdf documents because formatting is lost for those also with default Nutch ?

Comment: No, this plugin works only for HTML. For PDF and other documents Nutch relies on Apache Tika which extracts only the textual information. If you want to preserve formatting (when possible) then you need to write a custom plugin.

Comment: Thanks Jorge Luis ,Index-html worked properly for Html.

Comment: Jorge ,Due you have any idea how we can get rawcontent while indexing in nutch 1.14 version ?